# Convert Java's Integer to Scala's Int

Tags: java, scala

I have Java piece of code that returns `java.lang.Integer` and it can be `null`:

`someClass.getMyInteger`

But when I use it in Scala classes I'm getting this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   scala.Predef$.Integer2int(Predef.scala:357)

I.e. Scala implicitly tries to convert Java's `Integer` to Scala's `Int` (using implicit `Integer2int` method), but since in this case `Integer` is `null`  it fails with exception.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would wrap it in an Option:

```
val x = Option(someClass.getMyInteger).map {_.toInt}
```

E.g.,

```
scala> val oneInt: java.lang.Integer = 1
oneInt: Integer = 1

scala> val nullInt: java.lang.Integer = null
nullInt: Integer = null

scala> val oneOpt: Option[Int] = Option(oneInt).map {_.toInt}
oneOpt: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> val nullOpt: Option[Int] = Option(nullInt).map {_.toInt}
nullOpt: Option[Int] = None
```