# Correct way to go from a Java Integer to a Scala Int: toInt vs unbox?

Tags: java, scala, integer, scala-java-interop

Given a `java.lang.Integer` (possibly null), what's the correct way to turn it into a Scala Int?

Both of the following work just fine:

```
Option(possiblyNullJavaInteger).map(Int.unbox)

Option(possiblyNullJavaInteger).map(_.toInt)
```

What's the correct way (e.g. most efficient? "grammatically correct"? most readable?) of doing the conversion?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977168/convert-javas-integer-to-scalas-int

Answer (score 2):

I would wrap it in an `Option` and use `toInt`. As you said:

```
Option(possiblyNullJavaInteger).map(_.toInt)
```

This is the most sensible to me, it shows the intent more and matches up with things like `toString`